# What qualities are required for dogs competing in flyball?

Tags: dogs, pet-selection

I'm not sure I really understand where the difficulties are.

Is it only about team strategy? Or do the individual dogs have to be particularly suited to the game?

Of course they need to be fast, but is there more to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flyball can be a fun game for many different types of dogs, but if you are serious about being competitive:

- Temperament - first and foremost, your dog has to react appropriately to other dogs and people in a high energy environment. There is LOTS of barking at most competitions - how will your dog react to that?
- Health - a sound dog will have a long career. You must build up to a competitive shape and treat your dog as an athlete. If you have a couch dog and all of the sudden ask it to run fast, jump, hit the box, and turn tight many times in a row you are asking for an injury.
- Ground speed.
- Drive for fetching a ball: this can be taught to some extent but helps if they love balls.

When trying to find a compatible team you would consider at least the below:

- Temperament - the dogs are running fast and excited in close proximity - helps if they get along.
- Height - the jumps for any given team are set to the lowest jump height of that team. This is why many teams are comprised of several large dogs and one small dog to bring the jump height down.